# Is Source Film Maker on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Hello producers of animated pictures! I see that your website is mostly about the production about animated picture of the captured-from-honest-to-goodness-reality kind and wonder if you also care about the created-from-3D-models-in-a-computer-simulation kind and in particular questions on topics such as:

- Importing models and scenes
- Putting scenes together
- Animating characters in the scene
- Adding particle effects
- Managing cameras
- Managing the timeline
- Managing movement functions

...and not just from a theoretical point of view (e.g. "use <kbd>S</kbd> to move the camera backwards; you can adjust the motion speed like so, or link it to the character's head by clicking here and here and there").

If that is not the case we can amend [this answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9996/23) so it doesn't point to this site.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Film making is film making whether animated or live action. The most recent source film maker question we got is slightly borderline as it is more tech support in nature, but film making with source film maker is plenty on topic.